# Can't get the activity under test in an Android Espresso test

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

In our Espresso tests, we need to customize the launch intent to pass custom extras and so on. Therefore, we set the `launchActivity` flag to `false`:

```
@Rule
public final ActivityTestRule<CreateQuoteActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        CreateQuoteActivity.class, true, false
);
```

Now, I want to get a reference to the activity under test. If that flag was `true`, I would use `mActivityRule.getActivity()`. However, now `mActivityRule.getActivity()` returns `null`.

How can I get a reference to the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set that `launchActivity` to `false`, you only have access to the activity when you actually go ahead and launch it.

So, your activity context is right there:

```
final CreateQuoteActivity activity = mActivityRule.launchActivity(mIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `ActivityTestRule` you can configure an Intent for each test.

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(TAG_EXTRA, XXX);
    mActivityRule.launchActivity(intent);

    //......
}
```

If the intent is the same for all tests you can set it in the `@Before` method.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(TAG_EXTRA, XXX);
    mActivityRule.launchActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you launch an activity and then launch a second one after this you can use the method that has been posted [here](http://www.geekhole.uk/?p=98) that gets the currently resumed activity instance.

The basic code in question is as follows.

```
 public static Activity getActivityInstance() {
   getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         Collection resumedActivities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance()
               .getActivitiesInStage(RESUMED);
         if (resumedActivities.iterator().hasNext()) {
            resumedActivity = (Activity) resumedActivities.iterator().next();
         }
      }
   });
   return resumedActivity;
}
```

Comment: This is great as a more generic (and hackish) way to get the activity, thanks. Still, the answer for this case is more straight-forward. See the accepted answer.

Comment: How would that code compile? You never declare `resumedActivity` anywhere. And even if you had, it's set inside a `Runnable`.